# Use method to compare lists

Tags: java, list

I'm trying to use a method to compare t2o different lists. Basically I want to pass two different lists to a method which will return true or false if the elements of one array list are contained in the other using .contains. Right now it only returns true - and I'm not sure why. I'd like it to return false. If someone could help me figure this out, that would be great.

```
public class ArrayListTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

    list1.add("cat");
    list1.add("dog");
    list1.add("zebra");
    list1.add("lion");
    list1.add("mouse");

    //Test Values
    //list2.add("cat");
    list2.add("lizard");

    boolean doesitcontain = contains(list1, list2); 
    System.out.println(doesitcontain);


}

public static boolean contains (List<String>list1, List<String>list2){

boolean yesitcontains;

for(int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++){

    if(list2.contains(list1.get(i))){
        System.out.println("Duplicate: "+list1.get(i));
        yesitcontains = true;
        System.out.println(yesitcontains);
    }else{
        yesitcontains = false;
        System.out.println(yesitcontains);
    }
}
    if (yesitcontains = true){

        return true;

    }else 

        return false;

}

}
```

Comment: Do you care if `list2` has elements `list1` does not? If so, you ought to check both ways.

Comment: @2rs2ts Yes I am trying to check it both ways. Also having a little trouble again. Now everything just seems to return false, even I change the elements to the same thing.

Comment: Please edit your post with your updated code so I can have a look-see. :)

Comment: @2rs2ts Just did, now it only returns false

Comment: @dave: look at the loop. You are only checking the last element...

Comment: @jlordo Got. Your solution below is what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: NOTE to OP: I rolled back your last edit in order to preserve the context for the answers. Generally, never edit your question by turning it into a solution of the original question.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik Ok, you got it. And thanks for the notes on Algorithmic Complexity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me your method should be rewritten to:

```
public static boolean contains(List<String>list1, List<String>list2) {
    return list2.containsAll(list1);
}
```

The code you currently have actually only checks if the last element of `list1` is also in `list2`.

If you're actually looking for a *contains any*, this simple solution will do:

```
public static boolean contains(List<String>list1, List<String>list2) {
    for (String str : list1) {
        if (list2.contains(str)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: +1 That's what I was about to add to my answer. I would also mention how to avoid the O(n^2) pitfall.

Comment: Actually, I think OP is after `containsAny` (finding duplicates).

Comment: For generality, you could have `List<?>, List<?>` in method signature and just `for (Object o : list1) if (list2.contains(o)) return true; return false;` as implementation.

Answer (score 6):

1. You have inadvertently used the assignment operator where you intended the equality operator. In your specific case you should rewrite all this:

   ```
   if (yesitcontains = true){

       return true;

   }else 

      return false;

   }
   ```

   to just

   ```
   return yesitcontains;
   ```

   and avoid any chance of confusion.
2. Furthermore, your algorithm will not work because you should return `true` immediately when you see a duplicate. Instead you go on with the loop and "forget" your finding. You can expect this to always return `false` except if the very last elements coincide.
3. In a wider context, I should also give you the following general advice:

   - Avoid indexed iteration over lists. Not all lists are `ArrayList`s and may show O(n) complexity for `get(i)`. Instead use the *enhanced for* loop, which is safer, more concise, and more obvious;
   - Know the library: if you're just after confirming there are no duplicates, just [`Collections.disjoint(list1, list2)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#disjoint%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection%29) would give you what you need;
   - Be aware of algorithmic complexity: checking for duplicates in two lists is O(n<sup>2</sup>), but if you turn one of them into a `HashSet`, you'll get O(n).

Taking everything said above into account, the following would be an appropriate implementation:

```
static boolean disjoint(Collection<?> c1, Collection<?> c2) {
    for(Object o : c1) 
      if (c2.contains(o)) 
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

If you look at `Collections.disjoint`, you'll find this exact same loop, preceded by a piece of code which optimizes the usage of sets for reasons described above.

Comment: Maybe explain *why* this is better.

Comment: You ought to mention that OP was assigning, not comparing.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik One more concern. I switched to your recommendation. Now it only returns false even if both lists have the same elements.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik I just noticed. I change the values inside a for loop and thus the initialized boolean is what is returned. Can you tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

```
 if (yesitcontains = true){
```

should be

```
if (yesitcontains == true){
```

`==` is for comparison and `=` is for assignment.

`if (yesitcontains = true){`

will always evaluate to `if(true)` which causing `return true;`

EDIT:

(OR)

simply `return yesitcontains;` as commented.

Comment: Or easier: `if (yesitcontains) {`

Comment: Or easier: `return yesitcontains;` (I don't see why you would do anything else).

Answer (score 1):

```
if (yesitcontains == true)  { } // use `==` here
```

or just

```
if (yesitcontains) { }
```

The below code assigns `true` to `yesitcontains` , and the expression will always be `true`.

```
if (yesitcontains = true) { }
```

There is no point of `if()` in your code , you can simple `return yesitcontains;`